# Warnings in PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

I want to develop a litle project HTML/CSS

Because we are several people, I want to share it in GitHub, but there is a problem when I want to commit my project, I have a problem:

> No errors and 2 warnings found.

I don't understand why there is this problem.

Here are the codes of my project :

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: crimson;
}

img {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1096px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  img {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Desktop-First Responsive Build</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_Desktop_First.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Desktop-First Responsive Design</h1>

  <img src="images/image1.jpg">
  <img src="images/montBlanc.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```

Do you have any ideas on my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in PHPStorm or WebStorm you have to set `alt` attribute for `img` tag

try this

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image1-alt">
<img src="images/montBlanc.jpg" alt="montBlanc-alt">
```

or disable hinting in PHPStorm

```
Settings > Editor > Inspections > HTML > Accessibility > Missing required 'alt' attribute
```